# Code for commands in GAP

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, gap, semidirect-product, cayley-graphs

Is there a way we can check and refer the source codes which execute the commands like "CayleyGraph()", "SemidirectProduct()" which are used for computations in GAP software?

Comment: That answer of mine, and links given there should be sufficient, I suppose - if not, please  ask what's unclear.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much @Somos and

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov I'll check and ask any further questions